# C#: show row number in row headers of a System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid control

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagrid, .net-4.0, row

I can't find a way to show the row numbers in the row headers of a **System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid** control. Do you know how to solve this task for the .NET Framework version 4.0?

I'd like the row numbers to be shown when a System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid control has its data source populated as well as when a System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid control has been sorted by clicking on one of its columns' headers.

**Note**: Please note the question is about **System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid** control, - it's not about WPF or ASP.NET Datagrid controls, and it's not about System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView control.

Comment: Question - With your DataGrid - has the old dev made any dramatic customizations?

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer to keep the legacy code running as it's. Actually "sample code" to draw **System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid**'s rows and rows headers' icons ('star', pencil') is published  [here - DataGrid.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGrid.cs)  and [here - DataGridRow.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridRow.cs). It can be adapted to solve the subject task but it uses several internal methods and classes making its adaptation not straightforward.

Comment: Ok - I'm not the best UI guy in the world but I'll ask around and see if I can come up with something for you. No promises

Comment: Thank you anyway. I'm not experienced in WinForms UI drawing too: if somebody of your "around folks" are experienced in this WinForms UI area please warn them that this task seems to be non-trivial and could take quite some time. It's "just" needed to get simulated RowPostPaint event call or something like that but calculation of "currently being paint" DataGrid DataGridRow's row rowheader cell's rectangle bounds promise to be rather tricky C# coding exercise even with "ready to use" code snippets from .NET Framework sources I referred here.

Comment: FYI: Legacy code has about 45+ references to the DataGrid instance - and these are just direct references, there are more indirect ones passed by container classes instances: this is the reason I'd prefer to keep the legacy code intact - I can refactor it to use e.g. DataGridView but time is very limited currently in the project where this code is used.

Comment: I've spoken to a few and you're right - it's not a trivial task. One is a UI designer and if he has time he will look into it but he has stated that you're better off upgrading to DataGridView and adjusting the legacy code over doing a large redraw like this. I'll bookmark this and pass it onto him from this point. Goodluck :)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have already done the first step of the legacy code refactoring. And refactored code works well. (I believe) all of the DataGrid related coding is now encapsulated in a one custom class. The next step will be to replace DataGrid control with a TextBox control and a DataGridView control. DataGrid control is currently located within a custom control so the replacement promise to go smoothly.